# How many $2$'s are there between $1$ and $1000?$

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

The following is an interview question.

> Question: How many $2$'s are there between $1$ and $1000?$

For example, there are one copy of $2$ between $1$ and $10$ and $20$ copies of $2$'s between $1$ and $100.$

I calculated the above using brute-force. I think there should be an easier way to do this for large number such as $1000.$

Comment: There are actually $20$ occurrences of the digit "$2$" in the numbers $\{1,2,\cdots, 100\}$, though there are $19$ numbers in the same range where the digit "$2$" appears.

Comment: @Gae.S. You are right. Edited.

Comment: Hint:  For $10^n$;  there  are $10^{n-1}$ numbers that have $2$ in the units place, and $10^{n-1}$ that have a $2$ in the $10's$ place, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefix the numbers with $0$s so that they are all three digits, you can ask the number of $2$s in the range $000$ to $999$.  You should be able to convince yourself that the digits are equally distributed in this range.  There are $3000$ digits, so $300\ 2$s.  Deleting $000$ and adding $1000$ does not change the result.

Comment: Why are there $3000$ digits? So the final answer is $300$?

Comment: Because each number has $3$ digits and there are $1000$ of them. Yes, $300$

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the number of $2$'s in unit digits. There are $10$ such up to hundred and $100$ such $2's$ up to $1000$.

Then calculate all $2's$ in tens place. $10$ such up to hundred and $100$ up to $1000$.

Then calculate all $2's$ in hundreds place. $0$ such up to hundred and $100$ up to $1000$.

Therefore, total number of $2's$ are $20$ up to $100$ and $300$ up to one thousand.

Comment: 'upto' is not a word.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, ok corrected.